# Google shopping API barcode query

Tags: google-api, product, google-shopping-api, google-product-search

Is it possible to use the Google Shopping API to search for products by their EAN code (or barcode) and get the price list of all the current offers for that product?

I know that the old Google Shopping Search API was deprecated in 2013 and the current one was released in 2014 and I was wondering if it was possible to do it with the "new" API... I searched in the documentation but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: What about https://serpapi.com/shopping-results ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check though the documentation you have probably noticed that this is not something that is possible at this time.

It might be worth adding it as a feature request but as its a really old api i havent been able to find any issue forum for submitting such requests.

Comment: Thank you for your help!